# Multi-AZ with Auto-Failover for AWS ElastiCache for Redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, high-availability

There is an option "Multi-AZ with Auto-Failover" for AWS ElastiCache Redis
This option is not available for t2 instances

But even without this option TestFailover change primary node and update DNS.

The question: if it change master without auto-failover, what exactly does "Multi-AZ with Auto-Failover" ?